# Prolog DFS with a heuristic

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that chooses position for the next move in DFS on a board (top and right are given for a particular board - available moves):

```
neib(P1, P2) :- top(P1, P2).
neib(P1, P2) :- top(P2, P1).
neib(P1, P2) :- right(P1, P2).
neib(P1, P2) :- right(P2, P1).

neib(BoardPositionXY, NextBoardPositionXY)
```

Right now neighbour calculates `NextBoardPositionXY` in no particular order but I would like to first choose this `NextBoardPositionXY` that is the closest to solution that I am looking for. In python I would generate a list with all possible positions sort it by which one is the closest to solution and then loop over it. How can achieve that in prolog (I am quite new :))?

Comment: You can do it the same way as you describe. Collect possible solutions using bagof/3, assign weights to them, then sort (or simpler, extract the best).

Comment: Although not beginner-friendly, it is possible to write meta-interpreters in order to separate meaning and heuristics in a logic program. For instance, see the book Artificial Intelligence Techniques in Prolog by Yoav Shoham